# How to make the desktop color transparent, or remove the desktop color?

Tags: pi-4

I set the desktop background image to a transparent png image. I want the desktop color to be transparent as well.

Because I want to put the GUI on a transparent screen.

I manually changed the configuration file, but nothing worked.

The board I use is Raspberry PI 4B 4gb

Thank you for helping me!

[image]

Comment: You can't. What do you think you would see - there is nothing *behind* the Desktop?

Comment: What is the make and model of transparent screen? How does it work on a PC or Mac?

Comment: I'm using a 7-inch RGB screen.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have solved the problem, using the following method, but I haven't fully tested it yet.

```
sudo nano /etc/xdg/xdg-pi/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart
```

Add transparency Settings: In the open file, you need to add a line to set transparency. Add the following line to the end of the file:

```
@xsetroot -solid rgba:0x00/0x00/0x00/0x00
```

@CoderMike @Milliways  Thank